# Create a graph of authors as edge list from paired dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, theory

I am trying to create an adjacency list in python for coauthorship graph.
I have created a dictionary pf author

```
{'a1': ' A-ming Hao',
 'a2': ' Qing-zhen Wang',
 'a3': ' Xiao-long Li',
 'a4': ' Ming-da Zhai'}
```

I have created edge in this way.

```
g=nx.Graph()    

g.add_edge(y[0]['a1'],y[0]['a2'])
g.add_edge(y[0]['a2'],y[0]['a3'])
g.add_edge(y[0]['a3'],y[0]['a4'])
g.add_edge(y[0]['a4'],y[0]['a1'])
```

but I want to do it using for loop

```
for key,val in (y[0].items()):
    g.add_edge(y[0][key],y[0][key])
```

I want this loop to iterate through each key.
and create edge like this

```
g.add_edge(y[0][key],y[0][key+1])
```

so that an edge can be created between `key[a1]` and `key[a2],`.
in my for loop it is actually an edge between `key[a1]` and `key[a1]`.

and when it reach to last `key[a4]` connect it first `key[a1]`

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list slicing on the `dict.keys()` in combination with `zip()` to get your tuples to put into your graph:

```
authors = {'a1': ' A-ming Hao',
           'a2': ' Qing-zhen Wang',
           'a3': ' Xiao-long Li',
           'a4': ' Ming-da Zhai'}

keys = list(authors .keys())

# zip keys with itself - rotated by 1 element
tups = list(zip(keys, keys[1:]+keys[0:1]))

print(tups)
```

Output:

```
[('a1', 'a2'), ('a2', 'a3'), ('a3', 'a4'), ('a4', 'a1')]
```

with those tuples you can do:

```
g = nx.Graph()
for a,b in tups:
    g.add_edge(authors[a], authors[b])
```

---

You should keep in mind that the order in which keys are presented might vary - if you need to ensure insertion order you need to use:

- `python 3.7` up guarantees insertion order on dicts
- `CPython 3.6` up has insertion order by implementation detail/sideeffect
- or use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

to begin with ( or use `keys = sorted(d.keys())` )

---

For dict insertion order, read information @  [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)